# How to render custom controls like UILabel etc.. in iOS using OpenGL

Tags: ios

There is a requirement to create login page fully using OpenGL ES, Could anyone suggest me, What approach I need to follow ?

Please post the sample code for rendering custom UI controls in OpenGL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its plenty of work in pure opengl es. You will never do it same way usable and comfortable as the normal UI is. I suggest you to look at nifty-gui. Should be for ios and android. It allows to create quite nice UI using opengl with all the effects and styles. I used it for creating video player that not only renders video as gl textures but also has all the UI on gl. I think it is mostly used for games.

[image: Something like this]

http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:advanced:nifty_gui

http://void256.github.io/nifty-gui/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Umka.. could you please share me the sample project? Have you used this in iOS ?

Comment: I used it for desktop java and only saw it can also exist for ios. Sorry, cannot share it. Company I worked for owns it. If you will have any exact question on how to do things in nifty please feel free to ask. Will see if I can help. First of all figure out if it exists for ios and in what shape it is these days.

Comment: Do you know any other approach other than this? Is there any library is available in iOS to do this, so top of it, I can render the native controls, that will able to add  3d effects.

Comment: I don't think you can render native controls. You either use pure opengl and go things yourself with all the color picking for click, focus and text enter or you use some lib like nifty that already has it. May be some other libs exist. I'm not aware of.